# Can an OpAmp work shortcircuited to ground?

Tags: operational-amplifier

I am curious to know if an OpAmp can be work fine shortcircuited to ground.
Datasheets normally have information about the shortcircuit current that the component can deliver, but I understand that this is meaningful when you want to supply other components. 
But what about the OpAmp itself? Would it suffer if it is permanently driving its shortcircuit current?

This could be usefull when you have large capacitive loads. (Not interested in stability problems here)

An application note or any official information will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Some will suffer, some will not. Those that don't suffer may do so on higher supply rails. The devil is in the detail (and the data sheet) because there is no generic answer.

Answer (score 2):

Generally they are not designed to withstand a continuous short circuit to ground, so you'll negatively affect the long-term reliability, at best.

Exacerbating factors- ambient above 25°C, high supply voltage, more than one amplifier in a package shorted, more than momentary duration (thermal and electromigration failures can occur).

Even where "short circuit protection" is claimed, there are usually *weasel words* in the datasheet such as

> temperature and supply voltages must be limited to ensure that the dissipation rating is not exceeded

(TI TL071 datasheet). Since there is insufficient information to calculate the limits, they're really telling you that it's not something you should depend on.

The "short circuit" protection can usually be depended on for **brief** high current surges **occasionally** and for protection against sloppy probing on a PCB in a lab environment, but for anything else you're on your own and good luck.

Answer (score 1):

**Depends on the OpAmp design.**

This is a typical part of the Absolute Maximum Ratings section of the datasheet. See this example for the LM324.

[image]